# jQuery toggle element style but pausing briefly inbetween

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element which I am toggling the style of (like an on/off button). If it's currently 'on', change the style to 'off' and vice versa.

However, in some scenarios, I want to perform the above, but then revert to it's original state (cancelling out the toggle), but I want this to be reflected to the user by it's very brief change in style (so for 1/2 a second, it looks like it has changed style but then reverts back to it's original state.

I'm currently toggling the state of my button with the below code:

```
myButton.toggleClass('button-off').toggleClass('button-on');
```

I've tried chaining a `delay(500)` between the above and a 'flip' of the above line, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain more or put a jsfiddle.net code to see what you mean ?!

Comment: jQuery's delay is supposed to be used when you are chaining animations and not to replace a setTimout (as in the answer), see: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.toggleClass('button-off button-on');
    setTimeout(function() { that.toggleClass('button-off button-on'); }, 500);
});
```

You need to toggle both classes to switch between them.

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/asetor/2/edit)

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
myButton.toggleClass('button-off');
setTimeout(function() {
    myButton.toggleClass('button-on');
}, 500);
```